# Is it possible to derive circumference from these two points?

Tags: trigonometry

I have two points along one axis, call it y. I don't have the x axis coordinate because the points were taken as 1-D measurements. The angle between the points is known. Is it possible to derive a circle's circumference if both the points lie on it?

So say we have two points (x,y):

?,5 and ?,10

And the arc between these two points forms e.g. 30 degrees of the circumference of the circle the points lie on. What is the circumference?

I'm not sure there's enough information here to resolve it, but I'm no mathematician. Can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: No. You would at least need to know what the "y" coordinate of the center is.

Comment: The intercept on $x$ axis or $y$ axis is given by  $2\sqrt{g^2-c}$ and $2\sqrt{f^2-c}$ where circle is represented by $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$

Comment: So far i believe that stating an angle, and maybe just one extra condition even the slightest would be enough maybe even without it.

Comment: Am I right in thinking this can be done as long as the points are within 90 degrees of one another? I.e. by drawing a right-angled triangle using the Y axis difference between points as the opposite face and taking the provide angle, then using basic trig? It looks that way to me.

Comment: Actually whether it be 90 or any other angle it's just equivalent you can use more general law of sines and cosines.